# How to listen to variable event in Meteor Template event?

Tags: events, meteor, meteor-blaze

The question basically is how to convert this:

```
var evt = 'click' || 'touchstart'; // Based on some logic
$('.selector').on(evt, function(){});
```

into Meteor event handler

```
Template.MyTemp.events({
    ....??? : function(e, t){}
});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments below, seems like [chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080) is the problem, as it sets the touch events `passive = true`.

So the new question would be:

> How to set the passive property for event listeners in Blaze Template
>   Events?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple events in a single handler by using a `/` as a delimiter between the event types. [docs](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Event-Maps)

```
Template.MyTemp.events({
  'click/touchstart .selector'(e,t){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents default click after touchstart
    // your handler
  }
});
```

In english:

> for the template `MyTemp` handle click or touchstart events on the
>   `selector` class.

This is also useful reading: [touch and mouse](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/)

Comment: Won't that duplicate the event handler on touch devices?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't tried on mobile. I don't know if it's going to send two events or one.

Comment: Like i thought, it will fire twice. The idea behind the question anyway, is to listen for touchstart on mobile, and listen to click on desktop. And the reason, is that sometimes click doesn't respond as expected on mobile.

Comment: what if you stop propagation?

Comment: still fires twice

Comment: Based on my research, chrome sets the touch events passive = true, which makes it ignore stopPropagation [ref](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080).